# Which applications does Jira support?

Tags: tools, jira

Is [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) useful to use for Desktop Application, PHP based Application or Android based applications?

Answer (score 3):

[Jira](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIRA) is a very flexible tool. You can use it as a workflow management tool for managing any [software life-cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process).

It does not really need to know any knowledge of what kind of application you are developing. You can define any number of custom fields and or workflow steps you might need to differentiate between platform and or workflows.

I have used Jira extensively and I love it. Be sure to try the trial. For a small team (up to 10 users) it is very cheap, just 10 dollars.

The [Jira Capture](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/capture) tool is mainly focused on testing web-based applications, not sure you can use it to record and exploratory test Desktop and or Mobile applications.

Comment: +1 to the answer. Jira is not dependent on what project you are about to develop. It will help you with managing the workflow of your project.